# Alternatives to ST_OffsetCurve

Tags: postgis

I've created a query that creates a line that is perpendicular to my original line using `ST_OffsetCurve` to draw a line left and right of my original geometry, which I then select the line center of using `ST_Interpolate` and connect via `ST_MakeLine`. If I use a small distance (100m offset on a 1km line) it connects as expected and no topology errors are returned. However, if I increase the distance it becomes very prone to topology errors, which are thrown by GEOS. They are always "1st arg isnt a line" or "depth mismatch" errors. I should note that the lines are very 'blocky', as in they have many 90 degree turns, since it's satellite derived data.

I'm not entirely sure what causes it, but `ST_OffsetCurve` doesn't duplicate my line perfectly, there are always some artefacts to the left and the right, especially near the end of the line, which I believe to be the source of my errors.

I'd explain the code but I'm afraid it's not really easy to explain what's going on. There are five spatial functions jammed into one to form the line (transform, linemerge, line interpolate point, offset curve, remove repeated points). It's below if you care to take a look at it.

```sql
SELECT 
  ST_MakeLine(
    ST_Line_interpolate_point(
      ST_Transform(
        ST_OffsetCurve(  
          ST_RemoveRepeatedPoints( 
            ST_LineMerge( 
              ST_Transform( cl.geom,3857 )
            )
          ),
          {length},
          'quad_segs=0 join=bevel'
        ), 4326
      ), 0.5
    ), 
    (ST_Line_interpolate_point( 
      ST_Transform( 
        ST_OffsetCurve( 
          ST_RemoveRepeatedPoints( 
            ST_LineMerge( 
              ST_Transform( cl.geom,3857 )
            )
          ),
          -{length},
          'quad_segs=0 join=bevel'
        ), 4326
      ), 0.5
    )
  )
)
```

Which alternatives to `ST_OffsetCurve` do I have here, or is there perhaps something I'm doing wrong?

Alternatively, is there any way to perfectly offset the line without any deviation from the input line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'blocky' data will yield some weird errors with a mitre buffer, as it attempts to extend each edge of the line outwards. And yes, this likelihood of topology errors increases with larger buffer sizes.

Your best approach is to simplify the line before buffering. For instance, if you want a 2 km buffer, you could simplify the line by, (e.g.) 5% of the buffer distance:

```
ST_OffsetCurve(ST_Simplify(geom, 100.0), 2000.0, 'quad_segs=0 join=bevel')
```

But adjust the tolerance of [ST_Simplify](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Simplify.html) until it looks adequate (trial and error approach). Also you won't need ST_RemoveRepeatedPoints, since these repeated points will be removed by simplifying the geometries.

Comment: This worked brilliantly - the error ratio is reduced to roughly one to 30 (down from one to five on a 2km transect) while it still intersects my line in the fashion that I want it to. You've saved me many hours of work trying to find a workaround. Thank you!